# dynamic ordering with nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, dynamic-sql

Say you have a table named Articles.

It has the following columns:
ID, name, body, created, modified, pageviews, etc.

Using a single method, would it be possible to pull a list of articles, and pass it which column I want to order by?  And also the direction, i.e. desc or asc.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "single method" comment, but you can do this using [Criteria](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html):

```
IList articles = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Article))
  .AddOrder( Order.Asc("Name") )
  .List();
```

Obviously, you can wrap this in a method and pass the name of the property you want to order by as parameter as well as sorting direction. The latter is specified by `Order.Asc()` or `Order.Desc()`.

Comment: of course, if you're more comfortable using HQL, the equivalent would be "from article order by Name asc"

Comment: @joshua.ewer - you're right, and using HQL is _usually_ a better approach. However, in this case HQL would have to be dynamically generated which is less than ideal.